# How to bind and emit data simultaneously in Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel framework with Vue. I have a parent component which has a child component. The child component has a list of checkboxes, and whatever checkbox I tick, the value gets appended (or removed) from an array stored in data(). I am able to bind the input correctly to the array in the child component, but when I am emitting this array back to the parent component, the data is not fresh, ie it emits back an array with the result of the previous checkbox I ticked, not the current one. 
I wanted to know how to introduce a kind of delay between data binding and data-emitting so that I can emit back accurate data.

Child Component

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="color" :value="color" v-model="colors" @click="$emit('color', colors)" />

data() {
    return {
        colors: []
    }
},
```

Parent Component

```
<Child v-on:color="updateColors" />

data() {
    return {
        colorList: []
    }
}
updateColors(colors) {
    this.colorList = colors;
}
```

Output: When I first click on Red, the array emitted back is empty, when I then click on another color like Blue, then the array emitted back only has "Red".

Can someone help me out in binding data and emitting the same data simultaneously, or if not possible then introducing a delay which helps me to first save the data into the array and then emit the modified array back to the parent component?

Comment: use `@valuechanged` should work.

Comment: I tried using @valuechanged but now the array emitted back is always blank

Comment: oh, i missed that you emit with component data. I don't know why it would always empty, though. A [mcve] would really help

Comment: Thanks, will try to clarify my question more next time by referring that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) data properties in Vue and perform a function when they are changed. For example, in your child component you could watch the property `colors` and emit the `color` event only `colors` is changed;

```
watch: {
  colors: function(){
    this.$emit('color', this.colors);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. So we are only emitting after watching the array contents change, not the input. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change the event that emits the data.
Currently, you emit when `click` happens. But that is, as you mentioned, before the data is updated. To fix your problem, you could simply change the event to `@change`.

In any case, I would recommend you use a store to keep data between components in sync.
You can have a look at [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) for example, or build your own store. A handy feature to build your own store can be the newly integrated Vue.observable from Vue 2.6, see the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable)

Comment: I tried `@change` but the issue persisted, this is why I had to resolve for the `watch` property.